# Can't listen audio with Android emulator

Tags: android, audio, emulation

When I'm developing with Eclipse and the emulator is launched, I can't listen any audio on my computer, only emulator's sounds. I have disabled the emulator's audio but it stills lock.

I'm using Windows 7. If I go to Windows notification's bar, I click on Audio's Manager, I disable emulator's icon but nothing happens.

I would like to listen my mp3 or Youtube videos meanwhile I'm developing.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From emulator.exe -help-all

```
-no-audio                      disable audio support
```

> ========= help for option -no_audio:
>
> use '-no-audio' to disable all audio support in the emulator. this
>   may be   unfortunately be necessary in some cases:
>
> - at least two users have reported that their Windows machine
>     rebooted
>     instantly unless they used this option when starting the emulator.
>     it is very likely that the problem comes from buggy audio drivers.
> - on some Linux machines, the emulator might get stuck at startup
>     with
>     audio support enabled. this problem is hard to reproduce, but seems to
>     be related too to flaky ALSA / audio driver support.

Try:

Open a command into **android-sdk/tools** folder

```
emulator.exe -no-audio -avd YourAVD
```